# what is the use of the scenario's in atg? and how to implement them

Tags: atg

I am new to the ATG Framework can anybody please help where can i get the doc's and implementation examples and so on..

And what is the purpose of using the scenario's in atg?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scenarios in atg are like a workflow that a user is constantly in.  They allow business users to trigger events based on a users shopping personality. An example scenario could be to to give a user a certain promotion on their next order if they abandon a cart.

If you want more information, you can read the atg personalization programming guide or even the business user guide.  It seems like you are new to atg, I would recommend feeling your way around the entire platform before you dive head first into any serious programming.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario can be considered as a workflow engine. Based on some events users are directed to a page or an offer. It also helps business users to configure specific landing page for a given persona. ATG personalization guide would have detailed explanation of the concept. If you are looking for ATG tutorials and tips in general then you can refer [this](http://ourownjava.com/atg/) site.